# How do I create a "global variable" in Java such that all classes can access it?

Tags: java

here's my problem: I have multiple classes that are part of the same package and they need access to a certain file path

```
String filePath = "D:/Users/Mine/School/Java/CZ2002_Assignment/src/"
```

Rather than declaring the same Filepath in every single class, is it possible to simply have a "global" type of variable of this FilePath so that all classes can access it and I only need to declare and update it once.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

If you declare it as

```
public class TestClass {
    public static String filePath="D:/Users/Mine/School/Java/CZ2002_Assignment/src/";
}
```

It will be accessible everywhere as `TestClass.filePath`

This can be useful (and your use case makes sense) but public static variables are a double edged sword and shouldn't be overused to just be able to access things which change from anywhere as they can break encapsulation and make your program less clear.

If the string will never be changed for annother you can add the keyword `final`, which will enforce this never changing behaviour as well as allowing the JVM to make additional efficiency enhancements (that you don't need to worry about)

Comment: a perfect answer for what i need... you saved me from a lot of problems. respect :)

Answer (score 10):

```
public class Test {
  public static final String FILE_PATH = "D:/Users/Mine/School/Java/CZ2002_Assignment/src/";
}
```

Call it this way: `Test.FILE_PATH`

Note the `final` because you only want to declare it once.

There also used to be a [code convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.8.6) to name final constants all uppercase, with components separated by underscore "_" characters. In the end, it's probably a matter of preference though.

Comment: final: yes, vastly better.

Answer (score 2):

A word on `final` - if the string field is a *constant variable*, its value might be duplicated in many classes that reference it. We may want to avoid that because 1) the string is too big. 2) if the string is changed, we must recompile all classes that reference it.

We can avoid it by

```
public static final String filePath; 

static{ filePath="D:/Users/Mine/School/Java/CZ2002_Assignment/src/"; }
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.

Comment: Why have you separated out declaration and initialisation?

Comment: then the field is no longer a *contant variable*. the string won't be cloned in other classes that reference the field.

Comment: the 2nd line is not technically "initialization"; it's just an assignment. it is a definite assignment on a (yet) definitely unassigned final field.

Comment: ahh, I understand what you're doing now, avoiding the usual final behaviour

Comment: Interesting. However, do you consider that URL string really as too big? Recompiling could be an issue in a very large project and a lot of usages of the constant. Still interesting since I didn't know this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class One

{

 public final static String FILEPATH = "D:/Users/Mine/School/Java/CZ2002_Assignment/src/";

}//class one

public class Two

{


public static void main(String[] args)
{

//sample operation to access the filePath value

System.out.println(One.FILEPATH);

}//main

}//class Two
```

Note:

1) Ideally better to use a configuration file/properties file - that way you can change the path without recompilation.
2) Avoid using static variables! (almost always)
http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2011/06/03/java-static-variables-are-wrong-almost-always/