# How to store a value globally and retrieve in other classes in Java

Tags: java, spring, global-variables

I need to store a value which is passed from another web application in a variable and need to retrieve the same in other classes. I tried by storing in session and retrieving the same, but it is impacting a lot of files in the application which I don't want.

Also tried by storing it in a static variable by using getter and setter methods. Even this doesn't work as the value which is passed from other application will be changing/dynamic.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this in Java/Using Spring framework.

I am new bie in Java. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the 2 classes you are making are in different file

Comment: Please refer this below link. Might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939769/how-do-i-create-a-global-variable-in-java-such-that-all-classes-can-access-it

Answer (score 0):

You can use "static final" as you need to initialize the value only once.
This is what it seems to be from your question or I guess you need to elaborate it a little bit more as what is the exact scenario you want to use it in.

Comment: I tried using static variable to initialize the value, but if a different value comes then it is failing as static variables will be initialized only once.

Comment: do you want to assign value to the variable only once or again n again  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A{
int a = 10; 
}
class B{
A obj = new A();
System.out.println(obj.a);
}
```

Is this You want ??

Comment: No, consider there is method getTest() which is called in 5 classes. This method has to use the parameter which we wanted to store. The value which we are trying to store is passed from another web application and it is a dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

As Arvind suggested a solution to your problem could be a static variable, if the variable should be modifiable then it should not be final.

```
class GlobalVar{
    public static int a = 10;
}
```

Hope this is constructive for you?

Answer (score 0):

I could able fix this issue by setting the value in session using httpsession object and retrieving the value using RequestContextHolder spring API.

Thank you everyone for your responses.